# codeigniter export csv in windows platform

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

```
function export_csv(){
        $this->load->helper('csv');
        if(isset($_POST['term_val'])&&$_POST['term_val']<>'0'){

        $term   = $this->Search_model->get_term($_POST['term_val']);
        $term   = json_decode($term);
        }else{
        $term=array();
        }


     $orders    = $this->Order_model->get_orders_export($term,'place_order');

    if(count($orders)>0){
    foreach($orders as $order){
    $sublist['order_id']= $order->order_number;
    $sublist['ship_to']= $order->ship_firstname.' '.$order->ship_lastname;
    $sublist['order_date']= date('d-m-Y H:i:s',strtotime($order->ordered_on));
    $sublist['email_to']= $order->ship_email;
    $sublist['city']= $order->ship_city;
    $sublist['pincode']= $order->ship_zip;
    $sublist['ship_address']= $order->ship_address1.' , '.$order->ship_address2;
    $sublist['phone']= $order->ship_phone;
        $sublist['product_name']= $order->name;
    $sublist['product_id']= $order->product_id;
    $sublist['status']= $order->status;
    $sublist1[]= $sublist;
    }
    $delimiter = ";";
    $newline = "\r\n";
    $heading[]=array('order_id'=>'Order Id','ship_to'=>'Ship To','order_date'=>'Order Date','email_to'=>'Email To',
    'city'=>'City','pincode'=>'Pincode','ship_address'=>'Ship Address','phone'=>'Phone','product_name'=>'Product Name','product_id'=>'Product ID','status'=>'status');

    $get_csv=array_to_csv1($sublist1,$heading,$delimiter, $newline); 
    ob_start();
  $filename = "orders_" . date('Ymd') . ".xls";
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
  header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");


//  header("Content-type: text/x-csv");
    //header("Content-type: text/csv");
//  header("Content-type: application/csv");
//  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=orders".date('d-M-Y').".csv");    
    print_r($get_csv); 
    }else{

    redirect($this->config->item('admin_folder').'/orders');    
    }
    }
```

[image]

The above code is the controller function for export CSV and the image is the action taking place when exporting.

**Problem** : Actually if we export csv using codeigniter it is showing that image as shown above. If we press export csv using codeigniter it it should not show that image , it should directly export csv into excel .

Answer (score 2):

if you want to generate reports in csv format it is very easy with codeigniter. Your model function

```
function index(){
   return $query = $this->db->get('my_table');
   //Here you should note i am returning 
   //the query object instead of 
   //$query->result() or $query->result_array()
}
```

Now in controller

```
function get_report(){
  $this->load->model('my_model');
  $this->load->dbutil();
  $this->load->helper('file');
  // get the object
  $report = $this->my_model->index();
  //pass it to db utility function
  $new_report = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($report);
 //Now use it to write file. write_file helper function will do it
 write_file('csv_file.csv',$new_report);
 //Done
}
```

No externals are required everything is available in Codeigntier.
The above method will force the file to be downloaded instead of 
being opening. Cheers! If you want to write xml file it is easy too. 
Just use xml_from_result() method of dbutil and use write_file('xml_file.xml,$new_report) 
Visit these links they will help.

[Database Utility Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/utilities.html)

And

[File Helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/file_helper.html)

Comment: the above code is working which i posted but that window is showing, can we do any thing to hide that window

Comment: use write_file and it will force the file to be downloaded.

Comment: for me, write_file didn't make the file download. I had to load the download helper and use `force_download('csv_file.csv', $new_report)` instead of `write_file('csv_file.csv',$new_report)`

Answer (score -1):

```
***> if you are trying to generate reports in csv format then it will quite
> easy with codeigniter.***
```

**Place this code in your Controller**

```
function get_report()
    {
        $this->load->model('Main_Model');
        $this->load->dbutil();
        $this->load->helper('file');
        /* get the object   */
        $report = $this->Main_Model->print_report();
        $delimiter = ",";
        $newline = "\r\n";
        $new_report = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($report, $delimiter, $newline);
        write_file( 'application/third_party/file.csv', $new_report);
        $this->load->view('report_success.php');
   }
```

---

**Put this code into Model**

```
public function print_report()
    {
        return $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM Table_name");
    }
```

---

report_success.php is just Successful Notification.

Your Report is being Exported. Thank you

---

Finally Your "file.csv" is generated.
its basically stored at physical storage.
In CodeIgniter/application/third-party/file.csv

---

it works.
it will help you.